# Hyperledger fabric Network setup for different region

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the hyper-ledger fabric project, It works well, if i have all the keys and certificate of peers and orderer. I can create the channel and install chain-code.

I came across the scenario.

Let Assume, that we have 4 organisation A,B,C,D. Each one is in different region with different CA (Total 4 CA). 
Each organisation consist of 2 peers, 3 orderer and have there own channel, Let's assume ChannelA, ChannelB, ChannelC, ChannelD. This structure work well because everything is internal setup.
Now,Assuming that If organisation A and B become partner wanna do business. They have to communicate the each other. How the work flow go.Because the A and B already have there own channel and organisation setup. Now how A and B can bring their business on the existing one. Later stage if c and d  wanna join A and B. How flow works because they have all different key-pair, certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama

Let me tell you a bit concepts here 
In hyperledger fabric consortium is the top level and channels, organisations are comes under consortium

So in your question each organisation has their own CA and some peers, Orderers

So when org A creates channel and org B, C, D joins same channel it will be as your case

At any point of time any organisation can create channel and others can join only if participating orgs  should be in the same consortium

Comment: Lets say A organisation and B organisation is up and running, C wants to connect it its not possible

Comment: Not clear to me will you please make your question clear ?

Comment: I meant  when 2 organisation which has its own  orderer and its own channel already blockchain start making the block. After while organisation C  wants to join the 2 organisation channel, Is it  possible that organisation C can join the existing channel or can create new channel.